# We can't find the products matching the selection Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch, magento2.3.4

all the answers found on SO so far to the problem "We can't find the products matching the selection Magento 2.3.4" didn't help get products displaying on the catalog page even after ensuring the checklist that one of the posts mentioned was followed. As a matter of fact, this was working fine when the migration to Magento 2.3.4 was being tested. When I click on a couple of main menu items, they display the products. Accessing products through sub-menu items is returning the error message mentioned earlier. Kindly share what you think must have been causing this scenario.I can access any product by search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Viability of the product. it must be Catalog,Search. and also check Anchor tag of the category and let us know.